# Emacs Message: save sent mails

Tags: emacs, email

How do you make Emacs Message (`C-x m`) save outgoing mails?

Is there a standard way to do this?

You could `C-x C-s` but this is inefficient and easy to forget, besides, you can't be 100% it is the mail actually sent: you might have done some last minute changes that you later forgot about.

Could this (`save-buffer`) be invoked from a "send message" hook and be automated? (Like `text-mode-hook`.) If so, what hook? (How do you get the hooks of a mode?)

`BCC` to yourself: not very elegant?

`FCC`: seems to be best solution, still, must be automated, both invocation and a good file name generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the variable `gcc-self` to `T` for any groups you want to
archive.

See its documentation
[here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Group-Parameters.html).
(or `(gnus) Group Parameters`)

EDIT:
`gcc-self` isn't a « classic » variable, you've to set it via
`gnus-parameter`.

```
(setq gnus-parameters
      '((".*"
         (gcc-self . t))))
```

Comment: How do I set that variable? I don't get anything with `Describe variable` and `gcc-self`.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg: edited

Comment: @Daimrod Look for my solution too...

Comment: mail sending (c-x m) can be used without GNUS. So if this relies on GNUS then it's not the correct answer. In fact, if you press c-x m in GNUS mode, the gcc line is always automatically added by default.

Answer (score 2):

Just got this to work. Put in `.emacs`:

```
(defun save-sent-mail ()
  (write-file (format-time-string "~/Mail/sent/%Y-%m-%d_%T") nil) )
(add-hook 'message-send-hook 'save-sent-mail)
```

Comment: If Emacs fail send mail it would not call message-sen**t**-hook. But message-sen**d**-hook it call before ever try do so..

Answer (score 2):

I use more complicate solution:

```
(defconst my-safe-filename-char-regex "[[:alnum:]-_!.@]"
  "Safe file names.")

(defun my-clean-filename (filename)
  (mapconcat
   (lambda (ch) (or (when (string-match my-safe-filename-char-regex (char-to-string ch)) (char-to-string ch)) "-"))
   filename "") )

(defun my-message-save ()
  "Store message in `gnus-article-save-directory' after
successful sending. It is possible that mail rejected and I lost
it completely, this func save it for me."
  (unless (eq major-mode 'message-mode)
    (error "Attempt to call my-message-save in non message-mode buffer"))
  (make-directory gnus-article-save-directory t)
  (let ( (buf (current-buffer))
         (field-to (my-clean-filename (or (message-fetch-field "Newsgroups") (message-fetch-field "To"))))
         (field-subject (my-clean-filename (message-fetch-field "Subject")))
         file )
    (setq file (concat gnus-article-save-directory "/" (format-time-string "%F_%T") "_" field-to "_" field-subject))
    (with-temp-file file
      (insert-buffer buf)
      )) )
(add-hook 'message-sent-hook 'my-message-save)
```

Also note that I use **message-sent-hook** instead of **message-send-hook**.

Comment: "Also note that I use message-sent-hook instead of message-send-hook." I guess that means you know the difference, so please tell me :-)

Comment: If Emacs fail send mail it would not call message-sen**t**-hook. But message-sen**d**-hook it call before ever try do so...

Comment: Also I trapped in error with my example. Look for http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help/85745

Comment: I update code, now it properly handle **/** char in message fields.